# Tests for checking if a noun is generic

Tags: nouns, generic

I want to know if I should use 'Ø article' before a plural noun that is qualified by a relative pronoun clause. One way of knowing it is to ascertain if the noun is one of generic generalization (if it is; then Ø article), and to know it is a generic noun, often you insert 'usually,' 'always,' or 'sometimes' in the sentence. If you see little change in meaning, you decide the noun has a generic representation.

> 1. Cherries that are sprayed tend to keep better.

You don't see the original sense drastically changed in 1 if you insert 'usually' before 'tend.'

However, with 'always' before 'from' in the sentence below, the original meaning would not be drastically altered, I don't think, since the fact the potatoes were from this year's crop would stay the same, but the potatoes are a definite group of potatoes here and so it is not a generic noun.

> 2. The potatoes that you purchased in the store were from this year's crop.

Is there any other test in academia to ascertain whether a target noun is generic or not?

Comment: It's more complicated still. If you're considering two subsets of cherries, you'd include the definite article: 'We spray part of the crop, those trees in the bottom field. The cherries that are sprayed tend to keep better, but there are always people who want organically grown fruit.' // Context is almost always the deciding factor, but there are many shades of context. Article usage is an acquired skill.

Comment: Yes, I know that well. I was more looking at 'generic' nouns and how easily to distinguish them from other types of nouns. Bare plurals are often felt used inappropriately when they don't represent a generic set of things or people. I just want to know if there is a test to know if a target noun is generic or not. Literature introduces the one inserting 'usually,' 'always,' etc. But that doesn't seem like a surefire way. If you place 'always' in 2, that doesn't drastically change the meaning of the sentence. So you would almost decide the 'potatoes' are generic, but no it's not obviously.

Comment: You're probably best using the analysis you give with your _potatoes_ example. I'd say that there's a gradience involved here in any case; 'Potatoes that you purchased in [this] store were from this year's crop.' is quite acceptable after say 'I think that the potatoes you've been selling have been a bit on the old side, Mr Supermarket Manager'. It's probably to do with differing degrees of genericness. Article usage is a slowly acquired skill bordering on an art.

Comment: "'Potatoes that you purchased in [this] store were from this year's crop.' is quite acceptable after say 'I think that the potatoes you've been selling have been a bit on the old side, Mr Supermarket Manager'." ---- Because the Manager would like his statement to sound like a so generally accepted truth. Generic: so usual. Right?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Obviously if there's a definite article, it's a definite group of potatoes. And if there's no article, then it's potatoes in general. There's your test right there. Just check if there's an article present, and you have your answer.

Comment: @RegDwight I suspect that OP wants a foolproof rule to decide _when to use / omit_ the article. And Cobuild have a 100+-page monograph listing rules, sub rules....